# What is the opposite of sampling called?

Tags: discrete-signals, sampling, continuous-signals

We call the conversion from a continuous time signal $f(t)$ to a discrete time signal $f_s[k]$ "sampling". Is there a name for the reverse operation, i.e. creating a continuous time signal from a discrete time signal?

Comment: If by sampling you mean down-sampling, then the opposite is called up-sampling.

Comment: @user13107: Obviously Denwid does not.

Answer (score 15):

This is called reconstruction.

Comment: How is that different from interpolation?

Comment: Interpolation refers to the act of increasing the sample rate of a discrete-time signal, but after you interpolate, the signal is still discrete. The term used to indicate conversion back to a continuous-time signal is "reconstruction", as pichenettes indicated.

Comment: @JasonR: Yet the reconstructed continuous time function is called "[the interpolant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigonometric_interpolation)"?

Comment: @WanderingLogic: Nowhere on the linked-to page is the word "interpolant" used.

Comment: @PeterK.: sorry, wrong link.  The [interpolation page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpolation) uses "interpolant" 14 times.  Interpolation is a form of reconstruction where you are trying to find a continuous function that exactly matches at the sample points.  Various kinds of regressions, where you are trying to minimize a total error metric or trying to minimize the maximum error at the sample points would be another way to do reconstruction.  I was looking at the trigonometric interpolation page on wikipedia because doing the DFT is a common (interpolating) form of reconstruction.

Comment: The portion of the page that you cited is a broader mathematical definition of interpolation that isn't directly applicable to signal processing. There is a subsection on the page that specifically describes interpolation in the context of signal processing. The definition given there lines up with what I said above.

Comment: When I taught signal processing I never used the interpolation word because it gave students all kinds of wrong ideas - in particular, that things like 'connect the dots' linear interpolation or fancy spline/polynomial methods would be acceptable solutions to a problem whose solution, in the equally spaced samples case, is undebatably a low-pass filter at half the sample-rate. Interpolation suggests that you are making things up and that there's no right or wrong solution; while reconstruction connects deeply with the sampling problem and emphasizes that there is only one way things could be.

Answer (score 3):

The process of creating a Continuous time signal from Discrete time signal is called (in plain Signal processing terminology) as "Reconstruction". Another term you will find associated with this process is "Low Pass Filtering" as it's the process used for conversion

Comment: "Low Pass Filtering" is way too generic.  They are usually called, funnily enough, [reconstruction filters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reconstruction_filter).

Answer (score -2):

In mathematics it is called interpolation.  If you fill data in between data points (in signal processing we call them samples) it is called interpolation.  If you try to fill missing data outside the range of the collected data/samples, it is called extrapolation.  In signal processing, the operation of filling the data in between samples is called interpolation and the blocks that do this operation are called interpolation filters.

Comment: interpolated signal is still discrete signal, so basically sampled signal only but with increased or decreased sampling rate

Comment: No, in mathematics it is called interpolation.  You fit a curve passing through those data points or samples and you take the curve as the generating function so you know everywhere the function value.  Not just at some points.  This is a broader view.  In signal processing, you might call it as reconstruction.  Of course, this is just one of the different ways of reconstruction.